# VBA, Transfer specific columns over to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that transfers a student over to another sheet if the student is delayed. The student is delayed if enroll-period is 132 or less for a master's student and 130 and less for a bachelor student. This code copys all of the headers and takes all of the columns and data over to the new sheet if the student is delayed. I only need the data from columns A, B, D, G, H, I, M and put it over in the new sheet in columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, if the student is delayed. How should i change this code so it will do that?
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub findDelayedStudents()

Dim wsIn As Worksheet
Dim wsOut As Worksheet


Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base")
Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Delayed Students")


wsOut.Cells.ClearContents
wsIn.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A1")

Dim lLastInputRow As Long
Dim lCurrentInputRow As Long
Dim lCurrentOutputRow As Long


lLastInputRow = wsIn.Cells(wsIn.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCurrentOutputRow = 2


For lCurrentInputRow = lLastInputRow To 2 Step -1

If (wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 10) = "B" And wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 
5).Value <= 130) Or _
    (wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 10) = "M" And wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 
5).Value <= 132) Then


    wsIn.Rows(lCurrentInputRow).Copy 
Destination:=wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow, 1)
    lCurrentOutputRow = lCurrentOutputRow + 1
End If
Next lCurrentInputRow

wsIn.Range("A1").Select
Set wsIn = Nothing
Set wsOut = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `wsOut.Range("A" & lCurrentOutputRow).value=wsIn.Range("A" & lCurrentInputRow).value` no need to copy

Comment: @Chris You should not delete questions just because you got it answered. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367329/i-answered-a-question-and-now-its-gone

Answer (score 2):

Currently you copy over entire rows using the inbuild copy paste methods in this part of your code:

```
wsIn.Rows(lCurrentInputRow).Copy 
Destination:=wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow, 1)
lCurrentOutputRow = lCurrentOutputRow + 1
```

It would be easiest to replace that with cell wise replication of your values like such:

```
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,1) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,1) 'A to A
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,2) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,2) 'B to B
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,3) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,4) 'D to C
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,4) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,7) 'G to D
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,5) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,8) 'H to E
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,6) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,9) 'I to F
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow,7) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow,13) 'M to G
lCurrentOutputRow = lCurrentOutputRow + 1
```

To set the correct headers replace this part of your code:

```
wsIn.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A1")
```

With:

```
wsOut.Cells(1,1) = wsIn.Cells(1,1) 'A to A
wsOut.Cells(1,2) = wsIn.Cells(1,2) 'B to B
wsOut.Cells(1,3) = wsIn.Cells(1,4) 'D to C
wsOut.Cells(1,4) = wsIn.Cells(1,7) 'G to D
wsOut.Cells(1,5) = wsIn.Cells(1,8) 'H to E
wsOut.Cells(1,6) = wsIn.Cells(1,9) 'I to F
wsOut.Cells(1,7) = wsIn.Cells(1,13) 'M to G
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! But all of the headers for the columns are still in the sheet. And every second row is left empty how do i change this :)

Comment: `wsIn.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A1")` this row transfers your headers.

Comment: That every second row is empty would indicate that instead of adding 1 to `lCurrentOutputRow` you add 2 instead. Of you have the same row twice in the code.

Comment: Sorry I am not the best at coding how should i change:
wsIn.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A1")

Comment: Ah sorry, I get the point now. You can simply use the same copy paste sequence I posted in my answer, but replace `lCurrentOutputRow` and `lCurrentInputRow` with 1

Comment: I think it works now thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If an answer to your question is helpfull you can mark it as such by marking the green check next to the answer, upvoting it, or both.